# Thread safety in relational database triggers

Tags: triggers, thread-safety, relational-database

I have a question regarding the thread-safety of trigger operations in relational databases like mariadb or mysql

Imagine a table structure like

```
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| ID | NAME  | CATEGORY | OFFSET |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| 1  | name1 | CAT_1    | 0      |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| 2  | name2 | CAT_1    | 1      |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| 3  | name3 | CAT_2    | 0      |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| 4  | name4 | CAT_1    | 2      |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
| 5  | name5 | CAT_2    | 1      |
+----+-------+----------+--------+
```

Please note the value of column OFFSET in relation to CATEGORY. The offset increases by 1 everytime a record of a particular type is inserted.
For example the next record with id = 6 of type CAT_1 will have the value 3 for offset
and a record with id = 7 of type CAT_2 will have offset = 2

New records will be inserted via a rest API and the id and offset needs to returned in the response.
Now this process needs to have thread safety i.e no two records (even if invoked concurrently via HTTP request to the API) of the same category should have the same offset value.

One way I thought of doing this is via a before_insert trigger where it would read the last offset value of the to_be_inserted category and insert the new record with a +1.

What I am unsure about is if this process is thread-safe.
Can it result in a situation where two simultaneous inserts of same category will execute triggers that will read the same previous offset value and calculate the same current offset ?

If yes then what would be a thread-safe way of doing it ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes an `offset` like that is asking for trouble. Don't put an offset, put a timestamp -- which is not dependent on other records in the table. Then if you want to calculate an offset, do that by a query that sorts in timestamp sequence, then counts offsets.

Comment: (The only use for `before_trigger`s should be to validate, or format data looking only at the row being inserted, not to manipulate content by reference to other dynamic content.)

Comment: But as per my requirements, one can query the table by the category and offset like list the first 100 records of category cat_1 from offset 10.

Comment: Your "requirements" are not good design. Who gave them to you? What are they really trying to achieve? Do you understand the business context? Or is it your lecturer making stuff up because they've never worked in real business/with a real-life database?

Comment: At the worst, create a `VIEW` with offsets calculated from the `timestamp`. That's read-only and calculated after update, so won't affect performance of insert/won't risk thread safety or race conditions.